# Dynamics 365: How to get the Form Metadata?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

How to get Form Metadata via C#? I need to get info about all `OnChange` event handlers of the elements of specific Form (look at the screen on the bottom) throught console application (written on C#). I know how to get Entity Metadata, but I doesn't see any info about its forms inside of.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are not stored in Database for readily accessible as these are stored in formXML and quite not sure if we can access the events in easy way.

Still you can query the Entity form metadata for formXML/formJson and parse it for own usage.

```
https://crmorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/systemforms?$select=formjson,formxml&$filter=name%20eq%20%27Account%27
```

[Referred below from this blog](http://specifiedbehavior.com/Posts/2016-02-17-Dynamics-CRM-Find-event-handlers-for-form/)

> [image]

That blog have a sql query pulling the formXML out of on-prem database.

```
WITH x AS 
(
       SELECT FormId, e.Name, CAST(FormXml AS Xml) FormXml 
       FROM SystemForm sf
       JOIN Entity e ON sf.ObjectTypeCode = e.ObjectTypeCode AND e.OverwriteTime = '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000'
       WHERE e.Name = 'Account'
)
, y AS 
(
       SELECT 
              x.FormId,
              x.Name Entity, 
              x.FormXml, -- Uncomment to see the full form xml
              t.c.value('@name', 'varchar(max)') HandlerName,
              t.c.value('@attribute', 'varchar(max)') AttributeName,
              a.b.value('@libraryName', 'varchar(max)') Library,
              a.b.value('@functionName', 'varchar(max)') FunctionName,
              a.b.value('@enabled', 'varchar(16)') [Enabled],
              t.c.query('.') [t.c.query], 
              a.b.query('.') [a.b.query]
       FROM  x
       CROSS APPLY x.FormXml.nodes('/form/events/event') T(c)
       OUTER APPLY t.c.nodes('Handlers/Handler') a(b)
       WHERE t.c.value('count(Handlers/Handler)', 'int') > 0
)

SELECT 
       *
FROM y 
-- WHERE Enabled = 'true' -- This will exclude non-attribute related rows
ORDER BY y.Entity, y.HandlerName, y.Library, y.FunctionName
```

Comment: I use v8.2 and I get the error: Could not find a property named 'formjson' on type 'Microsoft.Dynamics.CRM.systemform. Is it possible to do the same for v8.2 instead of v9.1?

Comment: I get this error if I use your web request (with my endpoint).

Comment: @AndreyBushman then use this pls: crmorg.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.2/systemforms?$select=formxml&$filter=name%20eq%20%27Account%27

Comment: I get empty array at this case: ```{
  "@odata.context":"https://crmdev.softline.com/api/data/v8.2/$metadata#systemforms(formxml)","value":[
    
  ]
}```

Comment: I found the reason of such behavior: I am to use localized name. I.e. `Организация` instead of `Account`. Thank you!